# It was someone else

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image: empty crossword grid]

**Across**
1. "In coordination and cooperation"? The New Yorker uses these strange terms all over article (6)
6. Try to capture a cow, perhaps abruptly – it stands outside (6)
12. Presents moneymaker to Margaret and Bianca? (5)
13. Talk a lot about 5 down state (5)
14. People of Europe 11 down people of Westeros (7)
15. British singer left trapped in the middle of a river in Scotland (5)
17. Material produced by small workers of slightly suspicious type (4)
18. Scottish snooker champion tailed one unknown musician (7)
19. Running laps and skiing is popular here (4)
22. It was someone else who got together with dog in comic film (2,4,2,3)
24. Thriller writer grew up here to be a successful novelist (4,7)
25. Powerful monarch's golden temple's location half destroyed (4)
27. "Eternal city" in the Philippines refusing new walls at the easternmost extremity (7)
28. Conceal which member was the latest, and which the first, to join a union of 50 (4)
31. Place to 28 across in Vatican City after revolution? (5)
33. *(See 8 down)*
35. Cheers communist revolutionary by entrenching entrance to California vacation spot (5)
36. US city's thrown away broken tequila still (5)
37. Lifts described by people in TV spots? (6)
38. Sylvester Stallone is in Cannes, being shrewder than everybody else (6)

**Down**
2. Rage-inducing motorists go hard? So wrong! (8)
3. Hamburgers can be found near here with quarter pound steak at the core (4)
4. Spider-Man's girlfriend: "With love given, I matter at last", holding left arm of superhero (7)
5. Cancer perhaps got extra energy, being dominant (9)
6. Georgia includes a tiny part of Ossetia; it's the smallest state in the country (3)
7. Frank from Amsterdam visiting Caribbean Netherlands (4)
8/33a. Contact information of conservative-backing mother? One boy seen with ladies' clothing (5,7)
9. Maybe one US dollar is a small charge to be deducted from a large number? (4)
10. This city is deep in Siberia, not the edge of tropics (4)
11. A game: Giants vs. ? (7)
16. Testifies, with keen power of observation, about Rhineland city being on the rise (9)
20. Onassis regularly cut workers' payments (8)
21. Stands among earliest ancestors (7)
23. Journal containing text, regularly concerning food (7)
26. Mix a couple of additives in Chimay Bleue? (5)
28. Finnish FC All Blacks' pre-game ritual (4)
29. The same plan making one million (4)
30. Sounds like not many would carry on with long-drawn-out hostilities (4)
32. The eighth note in "Embraceable You"? (4)
34. Group of religious extremists beheaded a loved one? (3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solved grid should look like this:

> [image: Solved grid]

Clue explanations as follows:

> **Across**
>  1. "**In coordination and cooperation"? The New Yorker uses these** strange terms all over article (6) **[TREMAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic))** = TERMS* containing A (article)
>  6. Try to capture a cow, perhaps abruptly – **it stands outside** (6) GAZEBO = G(A + [ZEB(-u)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebu))O
>  12. **Presents moneymaker** to **Margaret and Bianca?** (5) **[MOONS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Uranus)** = def + cdef (‘moneymaker’ is slang for the buttocks, while Margaret and Bianca are both names of moons of Uranus)
>  13. Talk a lot about [sovereign] **state** (5) **GABON** = GAB ON (Talk a lot about)
>  14. **People of Europe** [against] people of Westeros (7) **[VANDALS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandals)** = V (against) + [ANDALS](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Andals)
>  15. **British singer** left trapped in the middle of a river in Scotland (5) **ADELE** = A + DE(L)E
>  17. **Material produced by small workers** of slightly suspicious type (4) **SILK** = S(-uspicious) + ILK
>  18. Scottish snooker champion tailed one unknown **musician** (7) **HENDRIX** = HENDR(-y) + I + X
>  19. Running laps and **skiing is popular here** (4) **ALPS** = LAPS*
>  22. It was someone else who got together with dog in comic **film** (2,4,2,3) **NO TIME TO DIE** = NOT I (It was someone else) + MET (got together with) + ODIE (dog in comic)
>  24. **[Thriller writer grew up here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary,_Indiana)** to be **[a successful novelist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Indiana)** (4,7) **GARY INDIANA** = ddef (Michael Jackson, writer of *Thriller*, grew up in the town of Gary, Indiana - there is also a novelist called Gary Indiana!)
>  25. **Powerful monarch**'s golden temple's location half destroyed (4) **TSAR** = [(-amri)TSAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Temple)
>  27. "**Eternal** city" in the Philippines refusing new walls at the easternmost extremity (7) **AGELESS** = [A(-n)GELES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angeles_City) + (-wall)S
>  28. **Conceal** which member was the latest, and which the first, to join a union of 50 (4) **HIDE** = HI (Hawaii) + DE (Delaware)
>  31. **Place to [hide]** in Vatican City after revolution? (5) **ATTIC** = [CITTA](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/italian-english/citta)<
>  33. (See 8 down)
>  35. Cheers communist revolutionary by entrenching entrance to **California vacation spot** (5) **[TAHOE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Tahoe)** = TA (Cheers) + [HO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ho_Chi_Minh) + E(-ntrancing)
>  36. US city's thrown away broken tequila **still** (5) **QUIET** = TEQUI(-la)*
>  37. **Lifts** described by people in TV spots? (6) **AMENDS** = A(MEN)DS
>  38. Sylvester Stallone is in Cannes, being **shrewder than everybody else** (6) **SLYEST** = SLY (Sylvester Stallone) + EST (‘is’ in Cannes)
>
>  **Down**
>  2. **Rage-inducing motorists** go hard? So wrong! (8) **ROADHOGS** = GOHARDSO*
>  3. **Hamburgers can be found near here** with quarter pound steak at the core (4) **[ELBE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbe)** = E (quarter) + LB (pound) + (-st)E(-ak)
>  4. Spider-Man's girlfriend: "With love given, I matter at last", holding left **arm of superhero** (7) **MJOLNIR** = MJ (Spider-Man’s girlfriend) + O (love) + L (left) + (-give)N + I )-matte)R
>  5. Cancer perhaps got extra energy, being **dominant** (9) **SOVEREIGN** = S(OVER + E)IGN
>  6. Georgia includes a tiny part of Ossetia; **it's the smallest state in the country** (3) **[GOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goa)** = G(O)A
>  7. **Frank from Amsterdam** visiting Caribbean Netherlands (4) **[ANNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_Frank)** = _AN NE_
>  8/33a. **Contact information** of conservative-backing mother? One boy seen with ladies' clothing (5,7) **EMAIL ADDRESS** = (-conservativ)E + MA (mother) + I (one) + LAD (boy) + DRESS (ladies’ clothing)
>  9. **Maybe one US dollar** is a small charge to be deducted from a large number? (4) **BILL** = BILL(-ion)
>  10. This city is deep in Siberia, not the edge of tropics (4) **OMSK** = (-t)OMSK &lit!
>  11. A game: Giants **vs.** ? (7) **AGAINST** = A + GIANTS*
>  16. **Testifies**, with keen power of observation, about Rhineland city being on the rise (9) **WITNESSES** = WIT(ESSEN<)S
>  20. Onassis regularly cut workers' **payments** (8) **PENSIONS** = PEONS (workers) containing (-o)N(-a)S(-s)I(-s)
>  21. **Stands** among earliest ancestors (7) **STANCES** = _ST ANCES_
>  23. Journal containing text, regularly **concerning food** (7) **DIETARY** = DIARY (Journal) containing (-t)E(-x)T
>  26. **Mix** a couple of additives in Chimay Bleue? (5) **ADDLE** = ALE containing (-a)DD(-itives)
>  28. [**Finnish FC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FC_Haka) All Blacks' pre-game ritual (4) **HAKA** ddef
>  29. **The same** plan making one million (4) **[IDEM](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idem)** =IDE(a → M)
>  30. Sounds like not many would **carry on with long-drawn-out hostilities** (4) **FEUD** = “FEW’D” (i.e. ‘few would’)
>  32. The eighth note in "Embraceable **You**"? (4) **THEE** = THE + (e_b_aceab_)E
>  34. Group of religious extremists beheaded **a loved one**? (3) **SIS** = (-i)SIS

One additional thing worth noting about this crossword - I believe its solved grid contains every letter of the alphabet! (In fact, almost every letter - with the exception of J, U and Z - appears at the start or end of a word in the grid.) Very likely a constraint the setter has placed among themselves during the creation process...

(PS I especially love the clue for 22A!)

Comment: I agree that 22a is nice, but 1a made me smile too.

Comment: Just edited the question to fix 27a. Sorry about that! I've stopped counting how many times I've confused a compass point with its exact opposite at this point...